# pg-promise - Example with procedure

Tags: node.js, postgresql, stored-procedures, pg-promise

I use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) for several projects. I read this:

> ## Functions and Procedures
>
> In PostgreSQL stored procedures are just functions that usually do not return anything.
>
> Suppose we want to call function findAudit to find audit records by user_id and   maximum timestamp. We can make such call as shown below:

```
db.func('findAudit', [123, new Date()])
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data); // printing the data returned
})
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error); // printing the error
});
```

The documentation provides examples except for this two functions. (Notice : excellent documentation otherwise)

Can someone provide an example for Procedure with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)?

PS: I know what is a stored-procedure in Postgresql but I didn't find example with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) (one who could fail/sucess) ...

Thanks

Comment: [The API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.proc) explains the syntax. Is there any problem using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL only supports functions, a procedure is considered to be such a function that either returns no data or a simple response, such as operation summary.

For that reason [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) implements method [proc](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#proc) that expects either no data or a single row/object of data.

```
const res = await db.proc('procName', [123, new Date()]);
//=> either null or a single object with OUT properties
```

**UPDATE**

Since PostgreSQL v11 came out, proper stored procedures are supported. And [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) has been updated where method [proc](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#proc) now supports only the new `CALL` syntax.

Comment: working also with an custom exception "RAISE Exception" like (RAISE 'Duplicate user ID: %', user_id USING ERRCODE = 'unique_violation';) ?

Comment: Custom exceptions are not presently supported.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since It was a closed issue, I didn't see it. Maybe in the future ^^. Not a bad think to say it on your github page , it could help another guys (who missed this issue)

Comment: I've placed it on my to-do list: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/TO-DO

Comment: thanks, Since you are on your to-do list, I tried now ES6 generator with db.task. Any way to pass another param (https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#generators use static value) ?

Comment: If you want to pass some context object into your task callback, you can do: `db.task.call(myContextObject, callback(t){var myContextObj = t.ctx.context})`.

Comment: thanks , i was troubled : Read too much documentation today ^^